# How do I store an entire file into an array?

Tags: arrays

so I want to store the file I read into an array  but I am not sure how to. I am trying to use an arraylist but when I compile it in the console I don't it is not the same as the text file

this is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    String line = null;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        fr = new FileReader("sample.txt");
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            list.add(line);
            line = br.readLine();

            for(String s : list){
                System.out.println(s);
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you copy this code from somewhere?  Hint: real programming is not about copy-and-paste.

Comment: no, i did this myself...

Comment: OK ... yea .. I see that now.

Comment: In your loop, you read 2 lines in one cycle, but you only add one line to list. Try to remove `line = br.readLine();` after `list.add(line);`. Also move `for(String s : list)` outside `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

it looks to me like you're double advancing your position in the file by having line=br.readLine() both in your while condition *and* after adding to the ArrayList.  Also, is there a reason that you're outputting the contents before you've processed the entire file instead of outside the while loop?

Comment: I don't usually use Java, but my initial gut feel was that this shouldn't be done manually in a loop anyway. Did a little bit of checking and confirmed that http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29 will do what you need in a single, already tested, and much more readable line of code